# Auto create subdomains of username in wordpress along with wordpress Multisite installation using subdomains

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, multisite

Here is the scenario, I want to create subdomains on Wordpress Multisite for a few users like *`username.yoursite.com`* I also want the Multisite installation to use subdomains *`site1.wordpress.com`*.
Any suggestions on achieving the same where username subdomains and site subdomain can co-exist?